# calling to twilio number from mobilephone

Tags: php, twilio, phone-call

I want to take my phone, call the twilio number and then talk with the person in the other side; and as the same with the sms.

I don't want "url" apps, or phone apps... (I made this that actually works http://luiscallcenter.netne.net/callcenter/index.php)... but  I don't want use this.. I want to use twilio as another phone number... ...

can you help me with some reference?... I read the API but all that is about web apps, but I don't want this and I'm confused.

Comment: you can't just use twilio as a proxy number. best you can do is program your twilio app to forward the call to another number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic Call Forwarding**

`http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=123-123-1234`

In the above URL, replace 123-123-1234 with your cellphone number. Then set this URL as your twilio voice URL. Then all calls coming to your twilio number will be forwarded to the given number. This service is offered by twilio itself.
(For more details, visit [here](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward))

**Twimlets Service by Twilio Labs**

You can use [this](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets) website provided by twilio to generate urls for some common use cases such as forwarding to a cell number, echo a message etc.

When using this feature, you dont have to do any actual coding. Just replace the necassary parts in the provided URL and set this URL as the voice URL in twilio.